# Generate .NET documentation using Sandcastle HelpFileBuilder on ubuntu using xbuild

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, sandcastle, xbuild

I have a travis CI workflow setup to build a sandcastle project. When running xbuild, I get the error given below. Can somebody help?

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS**.

`$ xbuild SandcastleARM.shfbproj
XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 4.0.5.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
Build started 2/2/2016 10:41:37 PM.`

`Project "/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj" (default target(s)):
Target CoreBuildHelp:
SHFB: warning BHT0001: Unable to get executing project: Unable to obtain matching project from the global collection. The specified project will be loaded but command line property overrides will be ignored.
SHFB: error BHT0002: Unable to build project '/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj': System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.SetGlobalProperty (System.String name, System.String escapedValue) [0x00000] in :0 
at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.MSBuild.BuildHelp.Execute () [0x00000] in :0 
Task "SandcastleBuilder.Utils.MSBuild.BuildHelp" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "CoreBuildHelp" in project "/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj".-- FAILED
Done building project "/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj".-- FAILED
Build FAILED.
Warnings:
/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj (default targets) ->
/home/travis/SandcastleHelpFileBuilder/SandcastleHelpFileBuilder.targets (CoreBuildHelp target) ->
SHFB: warning BHT0001: Unable to get executing project: Unable to obtain matching project from the global collection. The specified project will be loaded but command line property overrides will be ignored.
Errors:
/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj (default targets) ->
/home/travis/SandcastleHelpFileBuilder/SandcastleHelpFileBuilder.targets (CoreBuildHelp target) ->
SHFB: error BHT0002: Unable to build project '/home/travis/build/vivsriaus/ARMDoc/sdk/dotnet/src/ResourceManagement/Resource/Microsoft.Azure.ResourceManager/bin/Debug/dnxcore50/SandcastleARM.shfbproj': System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.SetGlobalProperty (System.String name, System.String escapedValue) [0x00000] in :0 
at SandcastleBuilder.Utils.MSBuild.BuildHelp.Execute () [0x00000] in :0 
1 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:01.7070770`

Answer (score 1):

Sandcastle is designed for Windows. You will have to use AppVeyor with a Windows VM.

Microsoft also has a new tool called docfx at GitHub which can run on Linux.